# Regarding Restful Web Service Response

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-mvc

We are now incorporating Restful Web Services in our System and as a result, both Browser and Mobile Clients are able to access our System available in single form (Clients access same code; No different backend code for different clients) successfully via Restful Web Service (i.e.)

**REQUEST:**
Technically, Restful Web Service API has been built above our existing system (Specifically built above Controller of MVC). Mobile Clients (be it Android (or) iOS (or) Windows) and Browser Client (Web forms) make uses the Restful API built, for ACCESSING our system and transmitting DATA to our system.

**RESPONSE:**
So, once we get data inside our system (Controller), it gets processed by moving back and forth from DAO and business layer and finally the processed data lands in Controller for it to be get returned to respective client. So, at this place, currently we determine the type of client from where the request is made (Mobile App or Browser) and

RETURN only processed DATA

```
        IF

    Client is 'Mobile App'                          (or)
```

RETURN both processed DATA + Name of Web View

```
         ELSE

    Client is 'Browser'
```

Note1: We are returning javax.ws.rs.core.Response object in both the cases.

Note2: processed DATA can be PlainText (or) XML (or) JSON (or) String

**TO CLARIFY:**
Now our question is, whether can we eliminate this IF-ELSE condition for returning the stuff (i.e.) is there a way to have only one RETURN statement returning generic stuff, irrespective of Client to which the stuff is returned? If so, then how does different Clients (in our case, Mobile App and Browser) interpretes the returned stuff and renders view to us?